# AWS OpsWorks vs AWS Beanstalk vs AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I would like to know what are the advantages and disadvantages of using AWS OpsWorks vs AWS Beanstalk and AWS CloudFormation?

I am interested in a system that can be auto scaled to handle any high number of simultaneous web requests (From 1000 requests per minute to 10 million rpm.), including a database layer that can be auto scalable as well.

Instead of having a separate instance for each app, Ideally I would like to share some hardware resources efficiently. In the past I have used mostly an EC2 instance + RDS + Cloudfront + S3

The stack system will host some high traffic ruby on rails apps that we are migrating from Heroku, also some python/django apps and some PHP apps as well.

Comment: This question is a bit off topic for Stackoverflow, but probably wouldn't fit well on ServerFault either... I have proposed a new site for questions like this, follow if you agree! http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82757/cloud-computing-platforms

Answer (score 74, accepted):

> I would like to know what are the advantages and disadvantages of using AWS OpsWorks vs AWS Beanstalk and AWS CLoudFormation?

The answer is: it depends.

AWS OpsWorks and AWS Beanstalk are (I've been told) simply different ways of managing your infrastructure, depending on how you think about it. CloudFormation is simply a way of templatizing your infrastructure.

Personally, I'm more familiar with Elastic Beanstalk, but to each their own. I prefer it because it can do deployments via Git. It is public information that Elastic Beanstalk uses CloudFormation under the hood to launch its environments.

For my projects, I use both in tandem. I use CloudFormation to construct a custom-configured VPC environment, S3 buckets and DynamoDB tables that I use for my app. Then I launch an Elastic Beanstalk environment inside of the custom VPC which knows how to speak to the S3/DynamoDB resources.

> I am interested in a system that can be auto scaled to handle any high number of simultaneous web requests (From 1000 requests per minute to 10 million rpm.), including a database layer that can be auto scalable as well.

Under the hood, OpsWorks and Elastic Beanstalk use EC2 + CloudWatch + Auto Scaling, which is capable of handling the loads you're talking about. RDS provides support for scalable SQL-based databases.

> Instead of having a separate instance for each app, Ideally I would like to share some hardware resources efficiently. In the past I have used mostly an EC2 instance + RDS + Cloudfront + S3

Depending on what you mean by "*some* hardware resources", you can always launch standalone EC2 instances alongside OpsWorks or Elastic Beanstalk environments. At present, Elastic Beanstalk supports one webapp per environment. I don't recall what OpsWorks supports.

> The stack system will host some high traffic ruby on rails apps that we are migrating from Heroku, also some python/django apps and some PHP apps as well.

All of this is fully supported by AWS. OpsWorks and Elastic Beanstalk have *optimized* themselves for an array of development environments (Ruby, Python and PHP are all on the list), while EC2 provides raw servers where you can install anything you'd like.

Comment: OpsWorks handles git deployments as well albeit differently. Where ElasticBeanstalk git deployments are pushed from a repo using a CLI, OpsWorks uses read-only access to a repo using SSH (or HTTPS if public repo).

Comment: @Ryan As mentioned does Beanstalk uses Cloud formation type templates in the background to create the infrastructure required.

Answer (score 27):

OpsWorks is an orchestration tool like Chef - in fact, it's derived from Chef - Puppet, Ansible or Saltstalk. You use Opsworks to specify the state that you want your network to be in by specifying the state that you want each resource - server instances, applications, storage - to be in. And you specify the state that you want each resource to be in by specifying the value that you want for each attribute of that state. For example, you might want the Apache service to be always up and running and start on boot-up with Apache as the user and Apache as the Linux group.

CloudFormation is a json template (**) that specifies the state of the resource(s) that you want to deploy i.e. you want to deploy an AWS EC2 micro t2 instance in us-east-1 as part of VPC 192.168.1.0/24. In the case of an EC2 instance, you can specify what should run on that resource through your custom bash script in the user-data section of the EC2 resource. CloudFormation is just a template. The template gets fleshed ourt as a running resource only if you run it either through the AWS Management Console for CloudFormation or if you run the aws cli command for Cloudformation i.e. aws cloudformation ...

ElasticBeanstalk is a PAAS- you can upload the specifically Ruby/Rails, node.js or Python/django or Python/Flask apps. If you're running anything else like Scala, Haskell or anything else, create a Docker image for it and upload that Docker image into Elastic Beanstalk (*).

You can do the uploading of your app into Elastic Beanstalk by either running the aws cli for CloudFormation or you create a recipe for Opsworks to upload your app into Elastic Beanstalk. You can also run the aws cli for Cloudformation through Opsworks.

(*) In fact, AWS's documentation on its Ruby app example was so poor that I lost patience and embedded the example app into a Docker image and uploaded the Docker image into Elastic Beanstalk.

(**) As of Sep 2016, Cloudformation also supports YAML templates.

Answer (score 10):

**AWS Beanstalk:**
It is Deploy and manage applications in the AWS cloud without worrying about the infrastructure that runs yor web applications with Elastic Beanstalk.
No need to worry about EC2 or else installations.

**AWS OpsWorks**
AWS OpsWorks is nothing but an application management service that makes it easy for the new DevOps users to model & manage the entire their application

Comment: I think this answer is inaccurate. The fact is the other way around. While Elastic Beanstalk is just a PaaS, with OpsWorks, it's all your responsibility to create a stack using appropriate components. 'For new DevOps' definition would apply to EB users, not OpsWorks'.

Comment: I don't think is correct, or at least things have changed quite a lot since this answer.

Answer (score 8):

In Opsworks you can share "roles" of layers across a stack to use less resources by combining the specific jobs an underlying instance maybe doing.

Layer Compatibility List (as long as security groups are properly set):

```
HA Proxy : custom, db-master, and memcached.
MySQL :  custom, lb, memcached, monitoring-master, nodejs-app, php-app, rails-app, and web.
Java : custom, db-master, and memcached.
Node.js : custom, db-master, memcached, and monitoring-master
PHP : custom, db-master, memcached, monitoring-master, and rails-app.
Rails :  custom, db-master, memcached, monitoring-master, php-app.
Static :  custom, db-master, memcached.
Custom : custom, db-master, lb, memcached, monitoring-master, nodejs-app, php-app, rails-app, and web 
Ganglia :  custom, db-master, memcached, php-app, rails-app. 
Memcached :  custom, db-master, lb, monitoring-master, nodejs-app, php-app, rails-app, and web.
```

reference : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/layers.html

Answer (score 4):

AWS CloudFormation - Create and Update your environments.

AWS Opsworks - Manage your systems inside that environments like we do with Chef or Puppet

AWS Beanstalk - Create, Manage and Deploy.

But personally I like CloudFormation and OpsWorks both by using its full power for what they are meant for.

Use CloudFormation to create your environment then you can call Opsworks from cloud formation scripts to launch your machine. Then you will have Opsworks stack to manage it. For example add a user in linux box by using Opsworks or do patching of your boxes using chef recipes. You can write down chef recipes for deployment also. Otherwise you can use CodeDeploy specifically build for deployment.

Answer (score 2):

**AWS OpsWorks** - This is a part of AWS management service. It helps to configure the application using scripting. It uses Chef as the devops framework for this application management and operation. 
There are templates which can be used for configuration of server, database, storage. The templates can also be customized to perform any other task. DevOps Engineers have control on application's dependencies and infrastructure.

**AWS Beanstalk** - It provides the environment for language like Java, Node Js, Python, Ruby Go. Elastic Bean stalk provide the resource to run the application. Developers not to worry about the infrastructure and they don't have control on infrastructure.

**AWS CloudFormation** - CloudFormation has sample templates to manage the AWS resources in order.

Answer (score 0):

As many others have commented AWS Beanstalk, AWS OpsWorks and AWS Cloud Formation offers different solutions for different problems.

In order to acomplish with

```
I am interested in a system that can be auto scaled to handle any high number of simultaneous web requests (From 1000 requests per minute to 10 million rpm.), including a database layer that can be auto scalable as well.
```

And taking into consideration you are in migration process I strongly recommend you to start taking a look at AWS Lambda & AWS DynamoDB solution (or hybrid one).

Both two are designed for **auto** scaling in a simple way and may be a very cheap solution.

Answer (score -1):

You should use OpsWorks in place of CloudFormation if you need to deploy an application that requires updates to its EC2 instances. If your application uses a lot of AWS resources and services, including EC2, use a combination of CloudFormation and OpsWorks

If your application will need other AWS resources, such as database or storage service. In this scenario, use CloudFormation to deploy Elastic Beanstalk along with the other resources.

Answer (score -2):

Just use terraform and ECS or EKS.

opsworks, elastic beanstalk and cloudformation old tech now. -)